# My application won't link using OpenSSL on Android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, openssl

I'm including OpenSSL in my Android project using [david-hoze/build-openssl-android: Builds openssl 1.1.0h with android ndk r17.](https://github.com/david-hoze/build-openssl-android).

This is my setup:
Android Studio 3.2
NDK version: 18.0.5002713

This is my app's `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

def my_openssl_dir = getRootDir().toString() + "/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my-company.my-app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++17 -frtti -fexceptions"
                arguments '-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared'
                arguments '-DMY_OPENSSL_DIR=' + my_openssl_dir
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = [
            ]
        }

    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.30'
}
```

This is my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
include_directories( src/main/cpp/
                   )

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             my-library

             SHARED

             src/main/cpp/my-code.cpp
             )

find_library (log-lib log)

add_library(libcrypto STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libcrypto PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
${MY_OPENSSL_DIR}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libcrypto.a)

add_library(libssl STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libssl PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
${MY_OPENSSL_DIR}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libssl.a)

target_include_directories(nativ PRIVATE
                       ${MY_OPENSSL_DIR}/${ANDROID_ABI}/include
                       )

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       my-library
                       libcrypto
                       libssl
                       ${log-lib}
                       )
```

And I'm getting these errors while compiling:

> Build command failed. Error while executing process
>   /home/david/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake with arguments
>   {--build
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/x86_64
>   --target my-library} [1/1] Linking CXX shared library ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86_64/libnativ.so
>   FAILED: : &&
>   /home/david/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++
>   --target=x86_64-none-linux-android21 --gcc-toolchain=/home/david/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
>   --sysroot=/home/david/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot -fPIC -isystem /home/david/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/x86_64-linux-android
>   -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -std=c++11 -std=c++17 -frtti -fexceptions -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -nostdlib++ --sysroot /home/david/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64
>   -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -L/home/david/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/x86_64
>   -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libnativ.so -o ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86_64/libnativ.so
>   CMakeFiles/my-library.dir/src/main/cpp/my-code.cpp.o
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libcrypto.a
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a
>   /home/david/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64/usr/lib64/liblog.so
>   -latomic -lm "/home/david/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/x86_64/libc++_shared.so"
>   && :
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_ciph.o):ssl_ciph.c:function
>   do_load_builtin_compressions_ossl_: error: undefined reference to
>   'COMP_get_type'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_ciph.o):ssl_ciph.c:function
>   do_load_builtin_compressions_ossl_: error: undefined reference to
>   'COMP_get_name'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_ciph.o):ssl_ciph.c:function
>   ssl_cipher_get_evp: error: undefined reference to 'FIPS_mode'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_ciph.o):ssl_ciph.c:function
>   ssl_cipher_get_evp: error: undefined reference to 'EVP_enc_null'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_ciph.o):ssl_ciph.c:function
>   ssl_create_cipher_list: error: undefined reference to 'FIPS_mode'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_ciph.o):ssl_ciph.c:function
>   ssl_create_cipher_list: error: undefined reference to 'FIPS_mode'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_ciph.o):ssl_ciph.c:function
>   SSL_COMP_add_compression_method: error: undefined reference to
>   'COMP_get_type'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_ciph.o):ssl_ciph.c:function
>   SSL_COMP_get_name: error: undefined reference to 'COMP_get_name'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_conf.o):ssl_conf.c:function
>   cmd_VerifyCAFile: error: undefined reference to
>   'X509_STORE_load_locations'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_conf.o):ssl_conf.c:function
>   cmd_ChainCAPath: error: undefined reference to
>   'X509_STORE_load_locations'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_conf.o):ssl_conf.c:function
>   cmd_ChainCAFile: error: undefined reference to
>   'X509_STORE_load_locations'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_conf.o):ssl_conf.c:function
>   cmd_VerifyCAPath: error: undefined reference to
>   'X509_STORE_load_locations'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function
>   SSL_read: error: undefined reference to 'ASYNC_WAIT_CTX_new'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function
>   SSL_peek: error: undefined reference to 'ASYNC_WAIT_CTX_new'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function
>   SSL_write: error: undefined reference to 'ASYNC_WAIT_CTX_new'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function
>   SSL_shutdown: error: undefined reference to 'ASYNC_WAIT_CTX_new'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function
>   SSL_CTX_new: error: undefined reference to 'FIPS_mode'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function
>   ssl_clear_cipher_ctx: error: undefined reference to 'COMP_CTX_free'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function
>   ssl_clear_cipher_ctx: error: undefined reference to 'COMP_CTX_free'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function
>   SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_dir: error: undefined reference to
>   'X509_LOOKUP_hash_dir'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function
>   SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_file: error: undefined reference to
>   'X509_LOOKUP_file'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function
>   SSL_free: error: undefined reference to 'ASYNC_WAIT_CTX_free'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function
>   SSL_get0_peer_scts: error: undefined reference to
>   'OCSP_response_get1_basic'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function
>   SSL_get0_peer_scts: error: undefined reference to 'OCSP_resp_count'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function
>   SSL_get0_peer_scts: error: undefined reference to 'OCSP_resp_get0'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function
>   SSL_get0_peer_scts: error: undefined reference to
>   'OCSP_SINGLERESP_get1_ext_d2i'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function
>   ssl_validate_ct: error: undefined reference to
>   'CT_POLICY_EVAL_CTX_new'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function
>   ssl_validate_ct: error: undefined reference to
>   'CT_POLICY_EVAL_CTX_set1_cert'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function
>   ssl_validate_ct: error: undefined reference to
>   'CT_POLICY_EVAL_CTX_set1_issuer'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function
>   ssl_validate_ct: error: undefined reference to
>   'CT_POLICY_EVAL_CTX_set_shared_CTLOG_STORE'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function
>   ssl_validate_ct: error: undefined reference to
>   'CT_POLICY_EVAL_CTX_set_time'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function
>   ssl_validate_ct: error: undefined reference to
>   'CT_POLICY_EVAL_CTX_free'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function
>   ssl_validate_ct: error: undefined reference to
>   'CT_POLICY_EVAL_CTX_free'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function
>   SSL_get_all_async_fds: error: undefined reference to
>   'ASYNC_WAIT_CTX_get_all_fds'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function
>   SSL_get_changed_async_fds: error: undefined reference to
>   'ASYNC_WAIT_CTX_get_changed_fds'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function
>   SSL_get_current_compression: error: undefined reference to
>   'COMP_CTX_get_method'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function
>   SSL_get_current_expansion: error: undefined reference to
>   'COMP_CTX_get_method'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function
>   SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths: error: undefined reference to
>   'X509_STORE_set_default_paths'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_rsa.o):ssl_rsa.c:function
>   SSL_use_certificate_file: error: undefined reference to
>   'PEM_read_bio_X509'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_rsa.o):ssl_rsa.c:function
>   SSL_use_RSAPrivateKey_file: error: undefined reference to
>   'PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_rsa.o):ssl_rsa.c:function
>   SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file: error: undefined reference to
>   'PEM_read_bio_X509'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_rsa.o):ssl_rsa.c:function
>   SSL_CTX_use_RSAPrivateKey_file: error: undefined reference to
>   'PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_rsa.o):ssl_rsa.c:function
>   SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file: error: undefined reference to
>   'PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_rsa.o):ssl_rsa.c:function
>   SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file: error: undefined reference to
>   'PEM_read_bio_X509'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_rsa.o):ssl_rsa.c:function
>   SSL_use_certificate_chain_file: error: undefined reference to
>   'PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_rsa.o):ssl_rsa.c:function
>   SSL_use_certificate_chain_file: error: undefined reference to
>   'PEM_read_bio_X509'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(statem_clnt.o):statem_clnt.c:function
>   ssl3_check_cert_and_algorithm: error: undefined reference to
>   'X509_certificate_type'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(statem_srvr.o):statem_srvr.c:function
>   tls_process_cert_verify: error: undefined reference to
>   'X509_certificate_type'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(t1_lib.o):t1_lib.c:function
>   ssl_get_auto_dh: error: undefined reference to
>   'BN_get_rfc3526_prime_3072'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(t1_lib.o):t1_lib.c:function
>   ssl_get_auto_dh: error: undefined reference to
>   'BN_get_rfc3526_prime_8192'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(tls_srp.o):tls_srp.c:function
>   SSL_srp_server_param_with_username: error: undefined reference to
>   'SRP_Calc_B'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(tls_srp.o):tls_srp.c:function
>   SSL_set_srp_server_param_pw: error: undefined reference to
>   'SRP_get_default_gN'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(tls_srp.o):tls_srp.c:function
>   SSL_set_srp_server_param_pw: error: undefined reference to
>   'SRP_create_verifier_BN'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(tls_srp.o):tls_srp.c:function
>   srp_generate_server_master_secret: error: undefined reference to
>   'SRP_Verify_A_mod_N'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(tls_srp.o):tls_srp.c:function
>   srp_generate_server_master_secret: error: undefined reference to
>   'SRP_Calc_u'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(tls_srp.o):tls_srp.c:function
>   srp_generate_server_master_secret: error: undefined reference to
>   'SRP_Calc_server_key'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(tls_srp.o):tls_srp.c:function
>   srp_generate_client_master_secret: error: undefined reference to
>   'SRP_Verify_B_mod_N'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(tls_srp.o):tls_srp.c:function
>   srp_generate_client_master_secret: error: undefined reference to
>   'SRP_Calc_u'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(tls_srp.o):tls_srp.c:function
>   srp_generate_client_master_secret: error: undefined reference to
>   'SRP_Calc_x'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(tls_srp.o):tls_srp.c:function
>   srp_generate_client_master_secret: error: undefined reference to
>   'SRP_Calc_client_key'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(tls_srp.o):tls_srp.c:function
>   srp_verify_server_param: error: undefined reference to
>   'SRP_check_known_gN_param'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(tls_srp.o):tls_srp.c:function
>   SRP_Calc_A_param: error: undefined reference to 'SRP_Calc_A'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl3_record.o):ssl3_record.c:function
>   ssl3_do_uncompress: error: undefined reference to 'COMP_expand_block'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl3_record.o):ssl3_record.c:function
>   ssl3_do_compress: error: undefined reference to 'COMP_compress_block'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(s3_enc.o):s3_enc.c:function
>   ssl3_change_cipher_state: error: undefined reference to
>   'COMP_CTX_free'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(s3_enc.o):s3_enc.c:function
>   ssl3_change_cipher_state: error: undefined reference to 'COMP_CTX_new'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(s3_enc.o):s3_enc.c:function
>   ssl3_change_cipher_state: error: undefined reference to
>   'COMP_CTX_free'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(s3_enc.o):s3_enc.c:function
>   ssl3_change_cipher_state: error: undefined reference to 'COMP_CTX_new'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_asn1.o):ssl_asn1.c:SSL_SESSION_ASN1_seq_tt:
>   error: undefined reference to 'UINT32_it'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_asn1.o):ssl_asn1.c:SSL_SESSION_ASN1_seq_tt:
>   error: undefined reference to 'INT32_it'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_asn1.o):ssl_asn1.c:SSL_SESSION_ASN1_seq_tt:
>   error: undefined reference to 'ZINT64_it'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_asn1.o):ssl_asn1.c:SSL_SESSION_ASN1_seq_tt:
>   error: undefined reference to 'ZINT64_it'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_asn1.o):ssl_asn1.c:SSL_SESSION_ASN1_seq_tt:
>   error: undefined reference to 'ZINT32_it'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_asn1.o):ssl_asn1.c:SSL_SESSION_ASN1_seq_tt:
>   error: undefined reference to 'ZUINT64_it'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_asn1.o):ssl_asn1.c:SSL_SESSION_ASN1_seq_tt:
>   error: undefined reference to 'ZUINT64_it'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_cert.o):ssl_cert.c:function
>   SSL_add_dir_cert_subjects_to_stack: error: undefined reference to
>   'OPENSSL_DIR_read'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_cert.o):ssl_cert.c:function
>   SSL_add_dir_cert_subjects_to_stack: error: undefined reference to
>   'OPENSSL_DIR_end'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(ssl_cert.o):ssl_cert.c:function
>   ssl_build_cert_chain: error: undefined reference to
>   'X509_verify_cert_error_string'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(t1_enc.o):t1_enc.c:function
>   tls1_change_cipher_state: error: undefined reference to 'COMP_CTX_new'
>   /home/david/dev/android/MyApplication/build-openssl-android/openssl-lib/x86_64/libssl.a(t1_enc.o):t1_enc.c:function
>   tls1_change_cipher_state: error: undefined reference to 'COMP_CTX_new'
>   clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation) ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Would appreciate your help.

Comment: *"I'm including OpenSSL in my Android project..."* - You should be using OpenSSL's official build procedure and not some random blog. Also see [Android](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android) on the OpenSSL wiki. That project uses some awful options to build the library. You should visit [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was the link order, I changed the order of `libssl` and `libcrypto` in my `CMakelists.txt` file like so:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
include_directories( src/main/cpp/
                   )

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             my-library

             SHARED

             src/main/cpp/my-code.cpp
             )

find_library (log-lib log)

add_library(libcrypto STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libcrypto PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
${MY_OPENSSL_DIR}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libcrypto.a)

add_library(libssl STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libssl PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
${MY_OPENSSL_DIR}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libssl.a)

target_include_directories(nativ PRIVATE
                       ${MY_OPENSSL_DIR}/${ANDROID_ABI}/include
                       )

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       my-library
                       libssl
                       libcrypto
                       ${log-lib}
                       )
```

And it compiles fine

Comment: Why exactly should the order matter?